# How can increase the speed of if statement in VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, if-statement

I am a beginner in VBA, and I have done this if statement to fill in a column in a excel table.
The function is working ok, however it took almost an hour to run.

I need to increase the speed of it.

Table1 has 2600 rows
Table2 has 3200 rows

Can I help me?

```
Sub PreencherO()

    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Dim His As Worksheet
    Dim Table1 As ListObject
    Dim Table2 As ListObject

    Set Table1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").ListObjects("Data")
    Set Table2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("His").ListObjects("Historical")

    Dim irow As Long
    irow = Table1.ListColumns(1).Range.Rows.Count

    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Table2.ListColumns(1).Range.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l As Integer

    For i = 2 To irow
        For l = 2 To lrow
            If Table1.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 6).Value = Table2.DataBodyRange.Cells(l, 6).Value Then
                Table1.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 20).Value = "OLD"
            End If
        Next l
    Next i
End Sub
```

I need to increase the speed of it.

Comment: Use a formula instead?

Comment: I know I can use a formula, however the cells will be empty have to be filled in by other user and he can not write if I use a formula. So I think in using vba code.

Comment: You have a `ListObject`. It will maintain the formula automatically as rows are added or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PreencherO()

    Dim Table1 As ListObject, Table2 As ListObject
    Dim i As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Table1 = .Sheets("Current").ListObjects("Data")
        Set Table2 = .Sheets("His").ListObjects("Historical")
    End With

    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' fill dictionary with historic values
    With Table2.DataBodyRange
        'Debug.Print "Table2", .Address
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, 6))
            If Len(key) > 0 Then
                 dict(key) = i
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' compare
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Table1.DataBodyRange
        'Debug.Print "Table1", .Address
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, 6))
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                 .Cells(i, 20).Value = "OLD"
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Completed in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation
End Sub
```